# Delete OTDS user using REST Api - Cannot delete synchronized objects

Tags: java, rest, opentext, ecm

I have been trying to find a way to delete a user using OTDS Rest web service, but I am not able to do so as I am receiving the following error while deleting a user.

```
"Cannot delete synchronized objects"
```

Can anyone please help on how can we delete user from OTDS using its REST Api?

I have tried to delete the user manually by using the OTDS Rest link, but still getting the following error.

```
http://<SERVERNAME>:<PORT>/otdsws/api/index.html?rest#!/users/deleteUser_delete_3
```

Error:

```
{
  "status": 3012,
  "error": "Cannot delete synchronized objects"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [documentation](http://docsapi.opentext.com/docs/pi_hosted/_org/ofh1/index.html?/otds160601-h-awc-en/s-usersdel.html) is quite clear that you can not delete users from synchronized partitions. This is considered a safety feature I think.

[image]